# Php Session Lock Wait timeout

Tags: linux, session, locking, php

I have wiered situation.

I have a proxy website and my shared hosting account allows maximum 25 processes for my account. 
I just started queuing multiple requests from a sinlge user using session lock. That means if there is already a request or user is already streaming a video, then his next request will wait untill the streaming ends. (And i had to apply this becuase users had started downloading multiple videos using downloaders at a time. The worse thing that downloader do, they normally request 4 times for a single download. In this way, only one user was using all my resources.)

The current problem is, the second request which is waiting, also take a separate process. In this way, only two users can reach my maximum 25 processes limit.

I am looking in PHP configuration to have something like Session Lock Wait time out, after that time (like: 20 Seconds), PHP should close the connection with any message or something. So we can just release process which is just waiting.

Please also tell me if someone know any linux solution for this.

Is there any linux command to get all the processes running for php scrips and which are in waiting mode?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 PHP shouldn't hang forever if the process can't lock the session file

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late for the person who asked this question, but the session can be unlocked before the script ends using function session_write_close(). You can do something like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
// ... use and/or update session data

session_write_close();

// begin streaming
header("Content-Type: foo/bar");

$f=fopen("hundred-meg-video.mp4","rb");
fpassthru($f);
fclose($f);
?>
```

Alternatively, you can re-open the session at the stream end. We use this to limit number of concurrent per-user downloads:

```
<?php
$limit=4;

session_start();

if ($_SESSION["concurrent_downloads"]>$limit) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
    echo "too many concurrent downloads";
    die;
}

ignore_user_abort(1); // if the user aborts the script, we still want it to continue running on the server
// otherwise the $_SESSION["concurrent_downloads"] would not decrease at its end

$_SESSION["concurrent_downloads"]++;
session_write_close();

// begin streaming
header("Content-Type: foo/bar");

$f=fopen("hundred-meg-video.mp4","rb");
fpassthru($f);
fclose($f);

// resume using session
@session_start(); // @ used to suppress "headers already sent" message
$_SESSION["concurrent_downloads"]--;
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't find any PHP option 'session lock timeout'

To list the session files accessed, try `lsof |grep session`

You should get a output like that
[image]

The line with the 16uW is the PHP process that locks the actual session files